# How do I remove a hover effect on a Wordpress Theme

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to remove this hover effect you see her on my website [www.skiathos.io](http://www.skiathos.io) but I can seem to find a way to do this using a CSS code so I don't destroy the theme.

Here is what I found it and what I tried

I tried this but with no luck

.hover-white { opacity: none !important; }

Comment: Hover effect *where*?

Comment: If you scroll down after the main photo and call to action... there are some images that have a white hover effect on them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it's not opacity of the image that changes, but the background color of the `::after` element of its parent, which covers the image. Therefore,

```
.works-grid.hover-white .work-item:hover .work-img:after {
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

... will fix it.

Comment: It worked, you are a star thank you

Answer (score 0):

do you override effect, see inspector and identify whats class is changed and override it.
In your case, is this original class:

```
.work-item:hover .work-img > img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05) translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05) translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05) translateZ(0);
    transform: scale(1.05) translateZ(0);
}

.work-item .work-img > img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.300, 0.100, 0.580, 1.000);
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.300, 0.100, 0.580, 1.000);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.300, 0.100, 0.580, 1.000);
}
```

If no effects, override hover effects like normal class, like this:

```
.work-item:hover .work-img > img, .work-item .work-img > img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.300, 0.100, 0.580, 1.000);
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.300, 0.100, 0.580, 1.000);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.300, 0.100, 0.580, 1.000);
}
```

Here hover action is like no action.